# Can we create a Rest API view using DRF to download a file from server?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a Rest API which downloads files from server. Can we do it using Django Rest Framework? Is this a valid case?

If yes a sample view snippet would be more helpful

Comment: Do you want to use DRF to trigger a file download for the client from a DRF endpoint?

Comment: @AaronLelevier Yes Aaron .. Can we do that using DRF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, DRF allows you to return any kind of response in its views, so you can return a file just like you would do in a regular Django view.

> There's no requirement for you to use the Response class, you can also return regular HttpResponse or StreamingHttpResponse objects from your views if required. [DRF API guide section](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/)